# jquery api call showing blank return

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, api

been trying to modify an api call to load via jquery after the page has loaded, someone else has helped me out but cannot get it to work. It is loaded in php, and im not sure if the syntax is correct.

http://staging3.cryptocritix.com - Look at the ICO's RECENTLY NOW TRADING widget

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'include' => "47,54,62,56,50,64,65",
        'max' => 10
    );
 if ( bp_has_groups( $args) ) :
        while ( bp_groups() ) : bp_the_group(); 
?>

<li>
    <?php
    $cmc_id = $setting['cmc_ticker'];
    $json_url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/'.$cmc_id.'/';
    ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $json_url ?>',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {                                               
      let ico_roi = data.price;
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      $(div).html(ico_roi);
      console.log(ico_roi);
      $('#price-showing-after-page-load').html(div);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</li>
```

the json url returns;

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17244475.0, 
        "total_supply": 17244475.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 7185.30010797, 
                "volume_24h": 4157028720.19653, 
                "market_cap": 123906728079.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.06, 
                "percent_change_24h": 2.22, 
                "percent_change_7d": 6.79
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1535841206
    }, 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1535840724, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors / unexpected behaviour are you getting, then? You can't expect us to guess what the nature of the issue is. What debugging have you done?

Comment: hi, ive dumbed it down to try to work out, and first hurdle is its not printing the data.price, im not sure if its correct syntax, 
i was getting the data via curl in php, someone else here at stackoverflow advised to use jquery to use document.ready function but not sure if its correct, do not know jquery

Comment: If the syntax was wrong you'd have a syntax error. Have you checked? I don't think you have. Also what does `data` look like? Does it definitely have a `price` property? What does `console.log(ico_roi);` print? Is it what you expected?

Comment: P.S. If you don't know jquery you could use native JavaScript to make the AJAX request, if you're more familiar with that.

Comment: Anyway, here's a demo which shows that the core of your code will work if a) your AJAX call succeeded, b) the data object contains a populated price property, and c) you have an element on your page with id "price-showing-after-page-load" which is visible. I don't have any of those pieces of information, so those are my assumptions. http://jsfiddle.net/ea9vm7yo/ . If it's not working for you, then probably one of those assumptions is incorrect.

Comment: hi appreciate your help, console.log does not show anything. Ive had a look at your jsfiddle, and I don't know how to get from var = data ={"price": [what to insert here] }; to get the price extracted from aboce json

Comment: I posted the answer. `var data = {
  "price": 123
};` in my demo was a replacement for the JSON data from the URL, just for the purpose of demonstration. It's not the method of extracting the data. I think you need to study JavaScript / jQuery and JSON syntax a bit more so you properly understand what you're looking at.

Comment: i didnt realise the data object i needed was nested. Thanks for your help, yes I do need to study JS/JQ , thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: it must have been nested when you were getting it via PHP, surely? The data structure doesn't change just because you use a different language to make the HTTP request. You must have had to do something similar to access it, going through the layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update containing the data.

The problem is simple - `price` is in a sub-property of the "data"->"quotes"->"USD" objects. It's 3 layers down, it's not a direct child of the root of the object. You can see this clearly by looking at the structure of the JSON. I assume when you had this code in PHP you had to access "price" in the same place in the structure.

Here's a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#price-showing-after-page-load').html(response.data.quotes.USD.price);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price-showing-after-page-load">

</div>
```

N.B. I have renamed the root object as "response" just to distinguish it from "data" which is a property of that object.

I also simplified it a bit - unless you have some CSS to go with it to change the style, there's really no need to create a new div just to hold the price value. In my code I insert it directly into the existing div.

Comment: thanks so much, this is the closest ive been for 2 days to getting this to work. It now shows the price for the first <li>. The other <li>'s are not working, despite console.log showing that it has fetched all prices. Any chance you could have a look at http://staging3.cryptocritix.com ?

Comment: there are no `<li>`s in the code example you've shown, and no code which updates more than one value, so I don't know the nature of the issue properly. And no I won't look at some random website, sorry. If you have a problem please show it here in the question. Also then others can benefit in future, long after the site has been fixed.

Comment: unsure how to replicate it in jsfiddle as each li has the "ticker id" which is on a my local db. Thanks again though

Comment: You can just hard-code the IDs for the purposes of a demo surely? Like you did in the question already

Comment: P.S. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick next to the question so it turns green) - thanks.

Comment: worked out the <li> issue, the function(response) needed a unique id. thanks again, can i buy you a coffee?

Comment: lol sure. If you can find one of these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRL1SeTJ1rk which serves coffee then I'll happily accept